# What is the logic behind entering Connecting The Pieces Dev Room?

Tags: antichamber

To enter Connecting The Pieces Dev Room, we will need to do something

> move the blocks across the field. But the field will not destroy the blocks, or will destroy some of the blocks only.

Why is it so? I find myself hard to understand this.

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you maybe give a screenshot of which room you are talking about?

Comment: Not sure which part of the screenshot that you want, so I will just post the part that I need explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks are only destroyed if they touch the **wall**, **floor**, or **ceiling**.

To pass this area you must move the blocks in a line (an ability granted when getting the yellow gun) and keep changing the direction before any blocks would hit a surface.

Here is a [video](http://youtu.be/t-TmEBoOYnQ) showing how you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. Ya, I actually saw the video, and this mechanism made me wonder why. I noticed during my playthrough, some blocks are destoryed when "entering" the field. Is that considered as wall as well?

Comment: Most likely.  The only things that should be destroying blocks in this area are the solid parts (i.e. if it stops you from moving then it would destroy the blocks running into it)

Comment: This area is visually-confusing due to the ultra-flat shaders being used; the fields are just along the edges of the rooms, and not crossing any of their openings.